# How to read file by sector,and not rely on the OS cache in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have any question: if Mac cache the file content, How to read any file by sector,and not rely on the OS cache in Cocoa. I use `initWithContentsOfURL:_fileURL options:NSUncachedRead error:NULL`, is it right? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The flag `NSDataReadingUncached` (or its deprecated synonym, `NSUncachedRead`) is a hint to the OS that the file should not be added to the cache.  They can be used to prevent large, unimportant files from being added to the cache and evicting other, more important data from the page cache.  And pay attention to the word "hint": the OS may freely ignore hints.

What are you actually trying to accomplish?

The OS ensures that the cache contains the same data as the disk, so no matter whether you read from the cache or read from the disk, you will always get the same data.  The only difference will be the performance.  So my best guess is that you must be trying to write a storage benchmark.

#### Solution

You can flush the cache by running the `purge` command (you can use `NSTask` for this).  This flushes the entire disk cache, so it will make your computer very slow until the cache warms up again.

This only works on OS X.  I don't have a solution for iOS.